# Image Capture Angular js using back camera for mobiles on Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to capture image using back camera for mobile ,Currently i am using video tag .I have tried using constraint like facingMode: "environment" but it dosen't work on chrome.I can't use input  type file with capture option as image capturing is mandatory for my application.Kindly help

Comment: Try navigating media devices there is function called Navigator.getUserMedia()
 which provides a list of devices (audio and video).You can then use ng -repeat to iterate between devices.